# Solve Ax = b using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I have a linear system of equations AX = B to solve in MATLAB. What I have known is A is sparse, positive-definite and symmetric. I know the command `x = A \ b` works yet I am not sure MATLAB takes full advantage of A's good properties so as to maximize the efficiency. Is there any way to specify the algorithm to solve it, for example Conjugate Gradient algorithm in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is sparse, you can use all these [iterative functions](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/linear-equations-iterative-methods.html), for example `bicg` for a biconjugate gradients method.

Comment: Thx. Is `bicg` really faster than `A \ b` in this case? Also, does it require the right-hand side is multiple-columns? If no, it means I need to call this function multiple times to get the full answer, but it may be slower, right?

Comment: @C.Wang I never use it, I've just searched into the doc. I think you must look at the examples, and try to benchmark each solution.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's `mldivide` operator does indeed take advantage of properties of `A`. See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) for details - expand the "Algorithm" section.